# Unity ScrollView

Tags: unity3d

использую UI ScrollView для скролла кнопок. Заметил, что скролл очень вялый. (Медленное ускорение и медленное замедление). Настраивал параметр "Deceleration Rate" но так и не добился необходимого эффекта, а именно сильное ускорение и быстрое замедление. Неужели у ScrollView нет отдельной настройки ускорения и замедления, придется писать свой скролл? Спасибо.